# Error GET /socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I can't solve this error of socket.io it shows in the console

GET /socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Refused to execute script from '/socket.io/socket.io.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
at script.js:1:14

I made this with node.js

The files are below (main server file is index.js)

index.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(app);
var { Server } = require("socket.io");
var io = new Server(server);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.get("/style.css", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/style.css");
});
app.get("/script.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/script.js");
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("chat message", (msg) => {
    io.emit("chat message", msg);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Socket.io</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </center>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

script.js

```js
var socket = io();
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
app.listen(3000);
```

with this:

```
server.listen(3000);
```

---

`app.listen()` creates a new server so the server you're starting is NOT the server that socket.io is hooked to, therefore the socket.io library is not hooked up to that server and when the request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` comes in, you don't get the socket.io JS library.

Here's the code for `app.listen()`:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

You can see that it creates a new server and then calls `.listen()` on that new server.

Your express code works because `app` is hooked to the server created by `app.listen()`, but socket.io is hooked to the server created by:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = new Server(server);
```

which is never started and is not running.  So, socket.io is never hooked up to the server that is actually running.  Instead, you should just create and start one server and hook both `app` and `socket.io` to that one server.

Comment: @Phil - The socket.io library (when properly hooked to the running http server) will serve that `/socket.io/socket.io.js` route automatically.  The reason that route is not being served is that the socket.io library is not configured to the server that is actually running.